# Not able to debug XQuery using XQuery Support + MarkLogic Debugger plugin in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, marklogic

I have installed **"XQuery Support + MarkLogic Debugger plugin"** in IntelliJ Idea Ultimate and want to debug XQuery. I followed all the steps that mentioned in [ML plugin config page](https://github.com/overstory/marklogic-intellij-plugin/wiki/Debugging-XQuery).

My requirement is to debug XQuery which is going to execute against App server so for that reason I selected **"Capture Appserver"** from "MarkLogic Run Mode" but I am getting error message like:

> Run Mode 'Capture Appserver' is only for debugging.  Choose 'AdHoc' or 'Invoke' for normal Run.

I don't know,  what mistake I am doing here? Please help me to fix this config issue and debug XQuery with MarkLogic.